# Python slash testing framework and vscode debugging

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to set a launch.json config file to be able to debug a slash run.

To run slash form the terminal I just need to:

```
slash run
```

This is my launch.json file:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "module": "slash",
        "args": [
            "run",
            "-vvv",
            "${file}"
        ],
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
      }
    ]
 }
```

But I receive

> No module named slash.**main**; 'slash' is a package and cannot be directly executed

This is the command vscode is trying to run:

```
c:; cd 'c:\Users\dev\projects'; & 'c:\Users\dev\projects\.venv\Scripts\python.exe' 'c:\Users\dev\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.4.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '65500' '--' '-m' 'slash' 'run' '-vvv'
```

A test example that slash can run:

```
# test_addition.py

import slash

def test_addition():
    pass
```

any idea on how I can get this working?

any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: do you have python interpreter set?
Also can you show your file? It seems you might have problem with how you are calling the splash.

Comment: yes I have the python interpreter set with venv and I can run slash from the console without problems. I'm on a Windows machine. And from the debug console I can see that vscode is taking the correct python interpreter from the virtual env

Comment: can you show your code for the file you're trying to run?

Comment: Which code? There are a bunch of tests and slash is a framework that runs them (like pytest).  I can't show you the tests code but I can add an example

Comment: Have you tried to enter "pip install slash" on the terminal to check whether the installation is successful

Comment: Slash is installed. I can run "slash run" from the Terminal without problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this.

Just create this launch.json inside the .vscode folder

```
{
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
      {
         "name": "slash testing",
         "type": "python",
         "request": "launch",
         "module": "slash.frontend.main",
         "args": [
             "run",
             "-vvv"
         ],
         "console": "integratedTerminal",
         "justMyCode": false
      }
   ]
}
```

So I needed to change the module name.